# SQL query to pull multiple addresses for Vendors in AX 2009

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to create a query that will be able to pull multiple addresses for Vendors out of Dynamics AX 2009. I have found a lot of what I need on the `VendTable`, but not all. I have about 500 Vendors with around 150 that have at least 2 addresses. Right now what I'm able to pull is just the first address.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT ven.CREATEDDATETIME
    ,'Organization' [Party, Record Type]
    ,VEN.NAME [Party, Name]
    ,VEN.NAMEALIAS [Search Name]
    ,VEN.LANGUAGEID [Party, Language]
    ,VEN.NAME [Party Address, Name]
    ,'Business/RemitTo' [Party Address, Purpose]
    ,VEN.COUNTRYREGIONID [Party Address, Country/Region]
    ,VEN.ZIPCODE [Party Address, SIP/postal code]
    ,VEN.STREET [Party Address, Street]
    ,VEN.CITY [Party Address, City]
    ,VEN.[STATE] [Party Address, State]
    ,CON.NAME [Party Contact, Description]
    ,'Phone' [Party Contact, Type]
    ,CON.PHONE [Party Contact, Locator]
    ,'' [Party Contact, Is Primary]
    ,VEN.ACCOUNTNUM [AccountNum]
    ,VEN.VENDGROUP [VendGroup]
    ,VEN.PAYMMODE [PaymMode]
    ,VEN.PAYMTERMID [Paym Term Id]
    ,VEN.CASHDISC [CashDisc]
    ,VEN.DLVMODE [Deliver Mode]
    ,VEN.DLVTERM [DlvTerm]
    ,VEN.W9 [W9]
    ,VEN.TAX1099REPORTS [Tax 1099 Report]
    ,VEN.TAX1099BOX [Tax 1099 Box]
    ,'' [Tax 1099 Name Choice]
    ,VEN.DBA [DBA]
    ,VEN.TAX1099REGNUM [Tax 1099 Reg Num]
    ,VEN.INVENTSITEID [Invent SiteId]
    ,VEN.INVENTLOCATION [Invent Location]
    ,VEN.TAXGROUP [Sales Tax Group]

    , * 
FROM VENDTABLE VEN
LEFT JOIN CONTACTPERSON CON ON con.VENDACCOUNT = ven.ACCOUNTNUM
WHERE ven.CREATEDDATETIME > '2018-04-30'
ORDER BY VEN.ACCOUNTNUM
```

After this, I need to find where the addresses are stored and how they are connected so that I can get both addresses when there are more than 1.

I did find a table `Address` that seems to have them all, but I cannot figure out how this table is connected to the `VendTable`.

Also is there a way to find what table is connected to a form in AX 2009? I have found some of the information that I need is in the Global Address Book, but that is not a table in the SQL DB.

**Update**

On the advice of @TEEKAY below, I looked up the `Datamodel` for [AX 2009](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa643886(v%3Dax.50)#relations) in an attempt to find a connection between the `Address` table and the `VendTable` table. All I could find was:
[image: Address table connection to VendTable]

However, this is not working. The `Address` table `AddrRecId` does match up to the `VendTable` `RecId`, but not on rows that would actually match data wise. Both tables have a field `Name` that holds the name of the vendor company like `All  Phase`. When matched using the `Address.AddrRecId = VendTable.RecId` I would get something like this:
[image: Party Address Name Not Match]
As you can see the Names don't match. But the `Address.AddrRecId = VendTable.RecId` do match.

Comment: This should get you to the datamodel or something close to it - http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2008/09/microsoft-dynamics-ax-40-data-model.html

Comment: @TEEKAY that is the data model for an earlier version of AX. Not compatible with the version that I have.

Comment: sorry. There are a few other questions on stackoverflow asking for similar things. I believe there is a common answer among most of them is to use the "Reverse Engineering" tool to export the model and then view it in Visio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa552178(v=ax.50)

Comment: @TEEKAY I don't have access to Visio. Is there another way to view whatever I can get from the `Reverse Engineering` tool? I've not used it before.

Comment: You mentioned in your update that you did the match on `Address.AddrRecId = VendTable.RecId`. Did you also include `Address.AddrTableId = VendTable.TableId` in the match? `RecId` values are only unique per table and `Address.AddrRecId` may contain values from several referenced tables, not only `VendTable` records.

Comment: @FH-Inway I tried, but there is no `TableId` in the `VendTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! It is the `DirPartyTable` that connects the 2 tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM VENDTABLE VEN
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE DIR ON DIR.PARTYID = VEN.PARTYID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS [ADD] ON [ADD].ADDRRECID = DIR.RECID AND [ADD].ADDRTABLEID = 2303
```

The final `[ADD].ADDRTABLEID = 2303` was needed to limit the results to just the VendTable, there are 2 other `ADDRTABLEID`'s, but I believe they are for the `CustTable` and possibly the `Contact` table.

It seems that Microsoft documentation is horribly outdated!

So the whole query is now like this:

```
SELECT 'Organization' [Party, Record Type]
    ,VEN.NAME [Party, Name]
    ,VEN.NAMEALIAS [Search Name]
    ,VEN.LANGUAGEID [Party, Language]
    ,VEN.NAME [Party Address, Name]
    ,CASE [ADD1].TYPE WHEN 0 THEN ''
                WHEN 1   THEN 'Invoice'
                WHEN 2   THEN 'Delivery'
                WHEN 3   THEN 'Alt. Delivery'
                WHEN 4   THEN 'SWIFT'
                WHEN 5   THEN 'Payment'
                WHEN 6   THEN 'Service'
                WHEN 7   THEN 'Home'
                WHEN 8   THEN 'Other'
                WHEN 9   THEN 'Business'
                WHEN 10  THEN 'Remit-To'
                WHEN 11  THEN 'Third-party Shipping Address'
                WHEN 100 THEN 'Remit-To'
        END AS [Party Address, Purpose]
    ,[ADD1].COUNTRYREGIONID [Party Address, Country/Region]
    ,[ADD1].ZIPCODE [Party Address, SIP/postal code]
    ,[ADD1].STREET [Party Address, Street]
    ,[ADD1].CITY [Party Address, City]
    ,[ADD1].[STATE] [Party Address, State]
    ,CASE WHEN CON.NAME IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CON.NAME END AS [Party Contact, Description]
    ,'Phone' [Party Contact, Type]
    ,VEN.PHONE [Party Contact, Locator]
    ,'' [Party Contact, Is Primary]
    ,VEN.ACCOUNTNUM [AccountNum]
    ,VEN.VENDGROUP [VendGroup]
    ,VEN.PAYMMODE [PaymMode]
    ,VEN.PAYMTERMID [Paym Term Id]
    ,VEN.CASHDISC [CashDisc]
    ,VEN.DLVMODE [Deliver Mode]
    ,VEN.DLVTERM [DlvTerm]
    ,VEN.W9 [W9]
    ,VEN.TAX1099REPORTS [Tax 1099 Report]
    ,VEN.TAX1099BOX [Tax 1099 Box]
    ,'' [Tax 1099 Name Choice]
    ,VEN.DBA [DBA]
    ,VEN.TAX1099REGNUM [Tax 1099 Reg Num]
    ,VEN.INVENTSITEID [Invent SiteId]
    ,VEN.INVENTLOCATION [Invent Location]
    ,VEN.TAXGROUP [Sales Tax Group]
    ,[ADD].NAME [Party Address, Name]
    ,CASE [ADD].TYPE WHEN 0 THEN ''
                WHEN 1   THEN 'Invoice'
                WHEN 2   THEN 'Delivery'
                WHEN 3   THEN 'Alt. Delivery'
                WHEN 4   THEN 'SWIFT'
                WHEN 5   THEN 'Payment'
                WHEN 6   THEN 'Service'
                WHEN 7   THEN 'Home'
                WHEN 8   THEN 'Other'
                WHEN 9   THEN 'Business'
                WHEN 10  THEN 'Remit-To'
                WHEN 11  THEN 'Third-party Shipping Address'
                WHEN 100 THEN 'Remit-To'
        END AS [Party Address, Purpose]
    , [ADD].COUNTRYREGIONID [Party Address, Country/Region]
    , [ADD].ZIPCODE [Party Address, ZIP/Postal code]
    , [ADD].STREET [Party Address, Street]
    , [ADD].CITY [Party Address, City]
    , [ADD].[STATE] [Party Address, State]
FROM VENDTABLE VEN
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE DIR ON DIR.PARTYID = VEN.PARTYID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS [ADD] ON [ADD].ADDRRECID = DIR.RECID AND [ADD].ADDRTABLEID = 2303
    AND [ADD].STREET <> VEN.STREET
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS [ADD1] ON [ADD1].ADDRRECID = DIR.RECID AND [ADD1].ADDRTABLEID = 2303
    AND [ADD1].STREET = VEN.STREET
LEFT JOIN CONTACTPERSON CON ON CON.VENDACCOUNT = VEN.ACCOUNTNUM
WHERE VEN.CREATEDDATETIME > '2018-04-30'
ORDER BY VEN.ACCOUNTNUM
```